# Python Django herança com atributo unique

Tags: python, django, herança, polimorfismo

estou com um pequeno problema.

```
class Pessoa(models.Model): 
cpf = BRCPFField(**unique=true**)

class Aluno(Pessoa):
 novo_atributo = ....

class Instrutor(Aluno):
 outro_atributo = ...

class Gestor(Pessoa):
class Meta: 
   proxy = True
```

Uma pessoa pode ser um aluno, um gestor e um aluno pode se tornar um instrutor, futuramente.

Quando eu cadastro um aluno com um CPF X, 100%. Mas quando eu tento registrar esse mesmo aluno(pessoa) com o CPF X como gestor, acusa erro pois o CPF está como unique. Como posso resolver isso?

Já tentei deixar a classe Pessoa como abstrata, porém o eu quero é deixar a tabela pessoa única, para evitar duplicidade. Pois uma mesma pessoa pode ser gestor, aluno e instrutor. Pensei na herança, pois ajuda bastante em relação ao banco.

Forms:

```
class PessoaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Pessoa
    fields = '__all__'


class GestorForm(PessoaForm):
   class Meta:
        model = Gestor
        fields = '__all__'


class AlunoForm(PessoaForm):
   class Meta:
        model = Aluno
        fields = '__all__'
```

Views:

```
class AlunoCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Aluno
    form_class = AlunoForm
    login_url = reverse_lazy('usuarios:login')


class GestorCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Gestor
    login_url = reverse_lazy('usuarios:login')
    form_class = GestorForm
```

Template Aluno_form:

```
<form class="row gx-3 gy-2 align-items-center needs-validation" method="post" action=""
      role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.media }}
    <div class="row g-3">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-floating">
                {{ form.cpf }}
                <label for="id_cpf">CPF</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-floating">
                {{ form.nome }}
                <label for="id_nome">Nome</label>
            </div>
        </div>            
    </div>           
    <div class="col-auto">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Enviar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Template Gestor_form:

```
<form class="row gx-3 gy-2 align-items-center needs-validation" method="post" action=""
      role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.media }}
    <div class="row g-3">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-floating">
                {{ form.cpf }}
                <label for="id_cpf">CPF</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-floating">
                {{ form.nome }}
                <label for="id_nome">Nome</label>
            </div>
        </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-floating">
                {{ form.funcao }}
                <label for="id_nome">Função</label>
            </div>
        </div>            
    </div>           
    <div class="col-auto">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Enviar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: unique no dj sera apenas 1 cpf não podera ter outro com os mesmo numeral podera fazer relacionamento 1 para 1, 1 uma pessoa pode ser um aluno e um aluno tbm pode ser um futuro instrutor.

Comment: Então, essa é a ideia, o problema é como fazer isso? pois no form, quando eu tento  cadastrar um aluno existente como membro de conselho, o sistema acusa erro por conta do cpf que já existe.

Comment: considerando que um aluno pode ser um instrutor e eventualmente um instrutor foi um aluno, adicionei uma chave estrangeiro ..   aluno_futuro_instrutor = models.ForeignKey(Aluno, related_name='vaga', on_delete=models.CASCADE).  ...na tabela instrutor model

Answer (score 0):

Faça de um modo que ao adicionar um aluno(pessoa) com o CPF X como gestor, esse cpf que está em aluno seja apagado antes de inserir em gestor. Ou então deixe esse CPF como chave estrangeira, pra ser chamado nos outros cargos.

EX:

```
class Pessoa(models.Model):
    nome = charfield....
    cpf_pessoa = models.charfield(max_length=11,unique=True)

class Aluno(models.Model):
    aluno = models.ForeignKey('Pessoa', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Gestor(models.Model):
    gestor = models.ForeignKey('Pessoa', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Assim, quando voce atribuir qualquer pessoa a gestor, ele ja vai herdar o CPF...